# AngularJS: Reload data on div with controller and ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, angularjs

I am new in Angular JS and learning it. I have a div and load data from json on startup with controller with following code but I want to reload it again when json object changed after performing specific action.

index.html

```
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html ng-app="ezpf" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="EZPF.Application.initialize()">
        <div id="btn-import" class="my-button button-small" onClick="EZPF.Application.openFile(this)">
                    <span class="button-title">Import</span>
                    <span class="button-help">This button will do something                         else.</span>                        
        </div>
        <div class="page" id="pro" ng-controller="ProductsListCtrl as store">
             <div ng-repeat="product in store.products.Products">                     
                  {{product.Title}}
             </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

myAngular.js

```
(function()
{
    var app = angular.module('ezpf', []);
    app.controller('ProductsListCtrl',['$scope', function($scope)
    {
        this.products = EZPF.Application.getProducts();     
        $scope.reload = function()        
        {           
            $scope.products = EZPF.Application.getProducts();           
        };
    }]);
})();
```

In following javascript file I am opening JSON file and reload products object with new data. After updating with new JSON file contents I have to reload data. I have tried to call reload from controller but its not working. Please help me, thanks in advance.

application.js

```
var EZPF;
if (!EZPF) 
    EZPF = {};
if (!EZPF.Application) 
    EZPF.Application = {};


EZPF.Application = 
{    
    products: [],
    getProducts: function()
    {
        if (this.products.length == 0) 
        {
            this.products = 
            {
                "Products": [
                {
                     "Title": "default name"
                     ....
                }]
            }
        }
        return this.products;
    },
    openFile: function()
    {
        var docsDir = air.File.documentsDirectory;
        try 
        {
            var jsonFilter = new air.FileFilter("JSON Files", "*.json");
            docsDir.browseForOpenMultiple("Select JSON Files", [jsonFilter]);
            docsDir.addEventListener(air.FileListEvent.SELECT_MULTIPLE, filesSelected);
        } 
        catch (error) 
        {
            air.trace("Failed:", error.message)
        }

        function filesSelected(event)
        {
            air.trace(event.files[0].nativePath);
            var myFile = new window.runtime.flash.filesystem.File();
            var file = myFile.resolvePath(event.files[0].nativePath);
            var fileStream = new air.FileStream();
            fileStream.open(file, air.FileMode.READ);
            this.products = fileStream.readMultiByte(fileStream.bytesAvailable, air.File.systemCharset);
            fileStream.close();
            air.trace(products);
            $('#pro').reload();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Is `EZPF.Application.getProducts()` returning something, does `$scope.products` gets updated?

Comment: @Zee EZPF.Application.getProducts() returns same JSON with new values but I don't know how to recall div controller that fill {{product.Title}}

Comment: After that line write `$scope.$apply()`, your div shud get updated.

Comment: @Zee Its not working, Is there any other way to call reload method inside controller from javascript?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: let me try the fiddle

Comment: Why you don't use `$http` or `$resource` for loading the json file? Still better is to define a REST API for exchange data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the `controller as` (`ng-controller="ProductsListCtrl as store"`) syntax, so you have to assign the variables to the controller itself (`this`) instead of the `$scope`:

```
var vm = this;

vm.products = EZPF.Application.getProducts();     
vm.reload = function()        
{           
    vm.products = EZPF.Application.getProducts();           
};
```

To reload the data:

```
<div class="page" id="pro" ng-controller="ProductsListCtrl as store">
    <div ng-repeat="product in store.products.Products">                     
        {{product.Title}}
    </div>
    <!-- Button for reloading the data -->
    <button ng-click="store.reload()">Reload Data</button>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/6738/)

Comment: Your are right but my problem is how to call `reload()` method from javascript after updating JSON?

Comment: I have added Reload Data button but not refreshing the data :-(

Comment: Is it AngularJS and JS communication fault? If I put again new hardcoded JSON inside `reload()` the refresh works but not working to call `getProducts()` method

Comment: Can you tell me how to call `reload()` programmetically from JavaScript instead of Reload button?

Comment: From within the controller you can just do `vm.reload()`

Comment: OK, thanks brother, I invoked `ng-click` of refresh button programmetically as `angular.element(document.getElementById('refresh')).triggerHandler('click');` from javascript method. Now I can read json file then its loaded automatically :)